# Htaccess Issue - Http Pages redirect to Home index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have pages with  redirecting to www.homage.com/index.php.

It should be redirecting to the www version. here my Htaccess File:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  
</IfModule>

# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mindscopeproducts\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mindscopeproducts.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mindscopeproducts.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

i.e. keep **external redirect** rule before other forwarding rules. Make sure to clear your browser cache when testing this.

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your rules like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on        
Options +FollowSymLinks

#Redirect non-www urls to www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mindscopeproducts\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mindscopeproducts.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: the index.php does not rewrite to .com. What am I getting wrong??